# Doctrine override relation accessor

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Say you have the following relations (altered for simplicity):

```
Dog:
  columns:
    id:         { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name:       { type: string,  notnull: true }

AwardType:
  columns:
    id:         { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name:       { type: string,  notnull: true }

Award:
  columns:
    dog_id:     { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    award_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    is_granted: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: false }
  relations:
    Dog:
      local:        dog_id
      foreign:      id
      type:         one
      foreignType:  many
      foreignAlias: Awards
    AwardType:
      local:        award_id
      foreign:      id
      type:         one
      foreignType:  many
      foreignAlias: Awards
```

With the above setup I can add a new dog and manually add Awards to that dog. I can also edit awards already granted to a dog.

When I call $myDog->getAwards() I want the set to include all granted awards (Award.is_granted==true && Award.dog_id==$myDog()->getId()) pluss all awards that have not been granted to that dog yet.

Is there an option that can be set in a model somewhere to make this happen? If not, what would be the best way to achieve it?

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and the bundled Doctrine 1.2 ORM.

[ Edit 1 ]
I realize I didn't explain the whole award thing properly, so I'll try to expand on it. Say you have the following AwardTypes:

- 1: Bone for not molesting postman
- 2: Collar for not biting Miss Molly
- 3: Bigger bone for chasing milkman (who we all know is evil)

Dog1 is already registered and has been granted AwardTypes 1 and 3. When editing that Dog the form should display AwardTypes 1 and 3 with a checked checkbox and AwardType 2 with an unchecked checkbox. This works great if Dog 1 has one entry in the Award table for each of the AwardTypes. Two with is_granted == true and one is_granted == false. So far so good.

When the user enters a new Dog the form should display all the AwardTypes, but with no checked checkboxes. When saving the new Dog a total of 3 rows should appear in the Awards table with the is_granted-flag set according to the checked-state of the checkboxes.

I know I can get all AwardTypes and check that against the AwardTypes a Dog has been granted already (showing all unchecked for new dogs, granted checked + not yet granted unchecked for existing dogs). What I am asking here is wether or not Doctrine has some magic that will give me compound sets as described above.

Comment: Do you mean a dog can be "not-granted" an award, or be granted a "non-award"? Why not make a getGrantedAwards() instead of overriding the existing method?

Comment: @greg0ire I expanded on the initial description above. I short: a dog can be 'not-granted' an award and then the forms and getAwards()-methods should return a number of Awards equal to the total number of AwardTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you have a problem modeling your data. It should probably look like this:

```
Dog:
  columns:
    id:         { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name:       { type: string,  notnull: true, unique: true }
  relations:
    Awards:
      class: Award
      foreignType: many
      type: many
      refClass: DogAward
      local: dog_id
      foreign: award_id

Award:
  columns:
    id:         { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    name:       { type: string,  notnull: true, unique: true }

DogAward:
  columns:
    dog_id:     { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    award_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
```

I have used a many-to-many relations, and added some constraint that I think might be useful in your case.
Symfony should generate a form looking like what you want, tell us if it is not the case.

Comment: Fails with the message "Couldn't find class Awards". If I change 'Awards:' under Dog->relations to 'Award' it goes a step further but fails with 'Invalid schema element named "classname" at path "Dog->relation->Award"'

Comment: @Christopher: my mistake, it's `class`, not `classname`. You can read more about defining many-to-many relations here : http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/nl/defining-models:relationships:join-table-associations#many-to-many

Comment: After some modifications to get the above schema to be pareseable by Symfony it still did not work. Only the already granted were shown in forms (empty if 'new'). Decided to remodel. I'll mark this as an accepted answer anyway. :)

Comment: @Christopher: thanks for the accept, but it's too bad you decided to remodel, there are tons of article on how to represent many-to-many relationships with a widget... all you would have to do would be to change the default widget with one of the solutions you can find on the web. Here is one solution with a double list : http://gestadieu.blogspot.com/2010/03/symfony-form-widget-for-many-to-many.html

Comment: @Christopher : here, another interesting post about choices : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-1-2-make-your-choice

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the method `getAwards()` method in lib/model/Dog.class.php

for example

```
public function getAwards(){
  return $query = $this->getTable()
    ->createQuery('a')
    ->where('a.dog_id = ?', $this->getId())
    ->addWhere('a.is_granted = ?', true);
    ->execute();
}
```

Please note, thats just a mockup, I didn't test it right now